# How to retrieve, compare and validate the value returned in Postman?

Tags: json, postman

I'm sending this request with these parameters:

```
GET {{url}}/xxxxx?max-size={{max-size}}

pm.test("Verify", () => {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200)
})
```

In `{{max-size}}` i defined the initial value of 100 and the current value of 200. My goal is to retrieve and validate that the returned value is within the value defined in the variable `{{max-size}}`.
Does anyone have any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

postman uses chai expect class so all chai expect conditions are supported:

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/

**in your case you can use "within" method:**

retrieve the json value and use:

```
pm.expect(2).to.be.within(0, 30);
```